# react-google-maps : Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-google-maps

I have this weird error (Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined) when I just import react-google-maps. Any idea?

```
import React from 'react';
import { GoogleMap } from 'react-google-maps';

class GoogleMapFlow extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>Hello World</div>
        );
    }
}

export default GoogleMapFlow;
```

Comment: what's the react version you're using?

Comment: did you solve this? i'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue with version 9.4.5 of react-google-maps, but react was v0.14.8. updating react to 16 solved the problem.

Comment: I went to  "react": "^15.6.0",